# JS filter array but do not filter if reverse present

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an array in the format coming out of d3js treemap using the `node.path(target)` on every node

```
var arr = [[{data: A},{data: B},{data: C}],
           [{data: C},{data: B},{data: A}],
           [{data: B},{data: D},{data: A}],
           [{data: A},{data: D},{data: B}]
          ]
```

I would like to filter the array to remove the reverse paths i.e `[{data: C},{data: B},{data: A}]` is the reverse of `[{data: A},{data: B},{data: C}]` so only `[{data: A},{data: B},{data: C}]` should be kept.

Thus final array should look like:

```
var finalarr = [[{data: A},{data: B},{data: C}],
                [{data: B},{data: D},{data: A}],
               ]
```

I have tried doing a simple reverse comparison.

```
function removereversepaths(arr){
 var cleanpaths = [];

 arr.forEach((a) => {
  var arev = [...a].reverse();
  if (!cleanpaths.includes(arev)){
   cleanpaths.push(a);
  } 
 });
}
```

I am wondering if I can write a filter function to perform this but for some reason I am drawing a blank on how to check the new array in the filter function for the reverse array. 
Any help/direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have only one property in the objects?

Comment: Can you show an example real or obfuscated data? The structure of the `{data: X}` should help us provide an answer.

Comment: @Barthy the data is actually like `[{data: A, value: '123'},{data: B, value: '213'},{data: C, value: '530'}]` for example. I simplified it because I only need to filter by the `data` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the filterd array as result and for lookup.

This solution takes takes `data` property for comparing and if the array is in reversed order, this array is filtered out.

To check if the array already exists in the `filtered` array, this array is iterated and checked with each element from the last to the first element and exit early if one array is found with objects with the same values.

```js
const compare = (a, b) => a.data === b.data; // or what ever suits

var array = [[{ data: 'A' }, { data: 'B' }, { data: 'C' }], [{ data: 'C' }, { data: 'B' }, { data: 'A' }], [{ data: 'B' }, { data: 'D' }, { data: 'A' }], [{ data: 'A' }, { data: 'D' }, { data: 'B' }]],
    filtered = [];

array.filter(a => {
    if (filtered.some(t => a.every((o, i, { length }) => compare(t[length - 1 - i], o)))) {
        return;
    }
    filtered.push(a);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you add a more detailed explanation of the code just for my understanding.